# datepicker works on widgets options page, but not on customizer

Tags: theme-customizer, datepicker

I have a widget with a date option field, which works correctly when in the dashboard, but fails to display when on the theme customizer.

I declare the field for the in the form() method like this (one input field for the date-picker, and another for the altField):

```php
$form .= '<span class="widget-field">';
$form .= sprintf(
        '<label for="%1$s">%2$s</label><input type="text" data-type="date" id="%1$s" name="%3$s" value="%4$s" class="date-picker widefat" >',
        $this->get_field_id( 'start-date-picker' ),
        __( 'From:', 'yosilosetheme' ),
        $this->get_field_name( 'start-date-picker' ),
        $start_v );

$form .= sprintf(
        '<input type="hidden" id="%1$s" name="%2$s" value="%3$s" class="realdata-date-picker widefat" >',
        $this->get_field_id( 'start-date' ),
        $this->get_field_name( 'start-date' ),
        $instance['start-date'] );
    $form .= '</span>';
```

In 'admin_enqueue_scripts" I enqueue jquery-datepicker and get the styles using:

```php
wp_register_style('jquery-ui', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui' );
```

and

```
wp_register_script( $this->_token . '-settings', esc_url( $this->assets_url ) . 'js/settings.js', array( 'jquery', 'jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-datepicker' ), $this->_version );
wp_enqueue_script( $this->_token . '-settings' );
```

settings.js holds this to look up the datepicker fields and activate them:

```js
$('body').on('focus', ".date-picker", function () {
    $(this).datepicker(
        $.extend({
                altField: $(this).parent().find('.realdata-date-picker'),
                altFormat: 'yymmdd'
            },
            $.datepicker.regional['es'])
    );
});
```

Again, this all words perfectly and as expected on the Dashboard, but it wont display the calendar in the theme customizer. I see that all the appropriate files are being loaded (jquery, jquery-ui styles, datepicker.js, etc); and on the debugger I can see that when focusing on these fields it does trigger the datepicker() call... but still nothing.

Someone has a clue on what's going on? (Wordpress 4.1)

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you figure this out? Care to share the solution? TIA

Comment: It's been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27921805/1924128